# Send JSON from Javascript and collect the value WebApi

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2

Search results I'm doing some stuff with javascript and I need to perform some operations d back-end And I decided to make apiweb UN , the problem comes when I make ajax request and since the return ( Made in c #) fails to collect Even the running data Method .

The first thing he did was to route Web API para Calling Methods Specific Power , I did as follows In WebConfig :

```
<code>
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiRouted",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param}",
    defaults: new { param = RouteParameter.Optional }
);</code>
```

After this operation I decided to make a specific method in ValuesController , which inherits from ApiController :

```
<code>
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Prueba([FromBody]Persona data)
{
    return Ok(new { message = "Llego" });
}

public class Persona
{
    public string username { set; get; }
    public string email { set; get; }
    public string password { set; get; }
}</code>
```

I have looked through many pages and have tried many examples and do not get that person entering take a value , the method is executed me but that person is null, instead I have also tried ICustomFormater , string , etc. With all those I have achieved the same result, the method is executed but not take input value .

From Javascrpt send it as follows

```
<code>var Persona = new Object()
    Persona.username ="Pepe";
    Persona.email ="Pepe@pepe.com";
    Persona.password ="12345";

$.ajax({

    url: "http://localhost:5311/api/values/Prueba",
    contentType: "application/json", 
    dataType: "json",
    data: Persona,
    type: 'POST',

    success: function (json) {

       alert(json.message)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
       alert("He petao")
    },

    complete: function (xhr, status) {

    }

});</code>
```

El resultado que me envia la webApi hacia el js si la recibo bien y en formato JSOn pero es que a la inversa no soy capaz de recoger el valor, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: You need to edit to translate in correct english the last paragraph please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route config look correct

The `Pruebla` action in `ValuesController` should only be decorated with one Http attribute. In this case is should be `[HttpPost]`...

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Prueba([FromBody]Persona data)
{
    return Ok(new { message = "Llego" });
}
```

You can create your `Persona` in JavaScript like...

```
var persona = {
    username: "Pepe",
    email: "Pepe@pepe.com",
    password: "12345"
};
```

And the call to the service will change slightly...

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://localhost:5311/api/values/Prueba',
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(persona),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (json) {    
       alert(json.message)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
       alert("He petao")
    },    
    complete: function (xhr, status) {

    }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you to answer, I tried your solution but i have a little problem. This 2 Lines don´t work: contentType: "application/json", and dataType: "json",
 When i use this 2 lines the call to the web api is error 400 if i remove this 2 lines the call arrive to the server but the param of the method (data) does not get a value, always is null. I am sending the Javascript since cordova in Visual studio 2015 to Web API in Visual studio 2015. I don´t understand why when i use this lines the call fails, do you know why can happend this?

Comment: Strange. trying using single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"`. Also inspect the request being sent. You could use Fiddler or the browser (F12)

Comment: Thank you so much, at now this work perfect, it is probably i copy some wrong.

Comment: De nada :). up vote if this answer was useful to you. Thanks.